# How to set SharePoint Choice Filter value from sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint

I am working on a SharePoint Page which has multiple Report Viewers and those reports get one parameter from a choice filter.

Currently, I need to type each choice:

[image]

Whenever there are something change, I need to go back to this filter and manually change it.
So, is there a way that I can get filer value from sql query? Or any other better solution?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint are you running?

Have you tried editing the parameter in report builder to pull the values from a SQL dataset?